# Error On Linking Basic CSFML Program

Tags: c

I have written a basic CSFML program to try to learn CSFML. When I try to compile it, I get a linker error. I can't figure out why this is happening. The program, compile command, and output of compiler are all below. I am on a rather clean copy of ubuntu.

**test.c:**

```
#include <SFML/Window.h>
#include <SFML/Graphics.h>
int main(){
    sfVideoMode mode = {800,600,32};
    sfRenderWindow *window = sfRenderWindow_create(mode,"Hello, CSFML", sfResize | sfClose, NULL);
    sfRectangleShape *shape = sfRectangleShape_create();
    sfRectangleShape_setFillColor(shape,sfWhite);
    while(sfRenderWindow_isOpen(window)){
            sfEvent event;
            while(sfRenderWindow_pollEvent(window,&event)){
                    if(event.type == sfEvtClosed){
                            sfRenderWindow_close(window);
                    }
            }
            sfRenderWindow_clear(window,sfBlack);
            sfRenderWindow_drawRectangleShape(window,shape,NULL);
            sfRenderWindow_display(window);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Compiled Using:**

```
gcc -o test test.c
```

**Output of gcc:**

```
/tmp/ccFCNmd7.o: In function `main':
csfmlTest.c:(.text+0x4b): undefined reference to `sfRenderWindow_create'

csfmlTest.c:(.text+0x54): undefined reference to `sfRectangleShape_create'

csfmlTest.c:(.text+0x5e): undefined reference to `sfWhite'

csfmlTest.c:(.text+0x6c): undefined reference to 
`sfRectangleShape_setFillColor'

csfmlTest.c:(.text+0x81): undefined reference to `sfRenderWindow_close'

csfmlTest.c:(.text+0x94): undefined reference to `sfRenderWindow_pollEvent'

csfmlTest.c:(.text+0x9e): undefined reference to `sfBlack'

csfmlTest.c:(.text+0xac): undefined reference to `sfRenderWindow_clear'

csfmlTest.c:(.text+0xc4): undefined reference to 
`sfRenderWindow_drawRectangleShape'

csfmlTest.c:(.text+0xd0): undefined reference to `sfRenderWindow_display'

csfmlTest.c:(.text+0xdc): undefined reference to `sfRenderWindow_isOpen'

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Use `gcc -Wall -O2 test.c -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -o test` to compile the program. The `-lsfml-graphics` tells the compiler to link the executable with the `sfml-graphics` library (`libsfml-graphics.so` or `libsfml-graphics.a` on Linux), and `-lsfml-window` similarly with the `sfml-window` library. (Note: `l` is "the letter ell", not "digit one", here.)

Comment: I tried that, but it says "/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsfml-graphics /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsfml-window" I installed csfml using "sudo apt-get install libcsfml-dev"

Comment: @BElgy: Use NominalAnimal's example, but use `-lcsfml-window` and `-lcsfml-graphics`. Looks like the 'c' is missing.

Comment: @NominalAnimal: Maybe you should post your response as an answer to this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per @NominalAnimal's comment:

Use `gcc -Wall -O2 test.c -lcsfml-graphics -lcsfml-window -o test` to compile the program.

The `-lcsfml-graphics` tells the compiler to link the executable with the csfml-graphics library ("libcsfml-graphics.so" or "libcsfml-graphics.a" on Linux), and `-lcsfml-window` similarly with the csfml-window library.

(Note: l is "the letter ell", not "digit one", here.)